# Delete contents of textbox and automatically deleting another

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have 2 input box fields, one linked to an autocomplete and the other is hidden

I have an action on select that takes the id of the selected item into the hidden field.

code:

```
    $('#id_emp_name').autocomplete({
    source: '/mycompany/employees.json',
    minLength: 1,
    dataType: 'json',
    max: 12,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#id_emp_id').val(ui.item.id);

    }
});
```

I want to change it so that whenever I delete contents (even a single character) on the autcomplete textbox it would set the hidden textbox's to `''`

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
$('#id_emp_name').autocomplete({
    source: '/mycompany/employees.json',
    minLength: 1,
    dataType: 'json',
    max: 12,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $('#id_emp_id').val(ui.item.id);

    }
}).keyup(function(){
    $('#id_emp_id').val('');
});
```

You may need to put some conditions on it of course.

Comment: I am very new to js/jquery but what sort of conditions? And as is it is not working.

Comment: Ahh, well I was thinking of something along the lines of testing if the `backspace` button was pressed within the `onkeyup` callback.

Comment: I get what you mean, can you kindly give me an example?

Comment: I've updated my example from `onkeyup` to `keyup` -- give it a shot now.